# NULL or NOT to NULL - Effects on performance

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm importing large JSON-data and translating it to a SQLite server. I'm using transactions for the inserts, and I've tried tables using NULL or not using NULL to check the difference in performance.

When I had tables in SQLite that looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    id TEXT, 
    author TEXT, 
    body TEXT, 
    score INTEGER, 
    created_utc TEXT
);
```

The import time was really slow, and searching in the table (e.g. select * from comments where author = 'blabla') was also slow.

When instead using a table with specified NULL or NOT NULL constraints, the import time and search time went much faster (from 2000 seconds to 600 seconds).

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    author TEXT NOT NULL, 
    body TEXT NULL, 
    score INTEGER NULL, 
    created_utc TEXT NULL
);
```

Does anyone know why this change in performance happened when using NULL or NOT NULL?

Comment: Adding PRIMARY KEY, would very likely have a significant impact. Really you should exclude that and re-test.

Comment: @MikeT okay, why is that? Has it something to with indexing?

Comment: Without PRIMARY KEY table will be indexed solely by **rowid** (the real underling PRIMARY KEY), with PRIMARY KEY an index (another) is created accordingly.[Rowid Tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)

Comment: @MikeT But how does that inflict performance? I read something about not having Primary Keys makes it harder for the database server to make sense of where to insert the specified row, and that may slow down performance

Comment: Because then it would have to make sense of each row by using many columns as the Primary Key, and that would slow down the process

Comment: Hopefully answer covers most of what you've asked. (*sorry a little rushed as I've got an appointment*)

Comment: In your example, you said queries using `where author = 'blabla'` were faster with a primary key on the `id` field. If that's accurate, it's surprising. The primary key will create an index on the `id` field only. Should not improve the performance of queries selecting on other fields.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson That may actually have been a temporary slowdown, and not affected by the primary keys. Didn't test that as thoroughly as the inserting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, adding `PRIMARY KEY` may be a major factor regarding improvements for searches. Although it may have a negative impact on inserts as the that index will have to be maintained.

Coding NULL makes no difference as it just leaves the NOT NULL flag as 0, so that can be ignored.

Coding `NOT NULL` may result in fewer inserts due to the constraint being met and could thus result in a performance improvement.

Regarding PRIMARY INDEX, coding this as anything other than `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` will result in a subsequent index being created.

That is, if a table is not defined with `WITHOUT ROWID` then SQLite creates the "REAL" primary index with a normally invisible column named **rowid**. This uniquely identifies a row. (Try `SELECT rowid FROM comments`)

As such, in both scenarios there is an index based upon the rowid. For all intents and purposes this will be the order in which the rows were inserted.

In the second scenario there will be 2 indexes the "REAL" primary index based upon the rowid and the defined primary index based upon the id column. There would be some impact on inserts due to the 2nd index needing to be maintained.

So say you search the id column for id x, in the first table it will be relatively slow as it's got to search according to rowid order, it's all it has. However, adding the index according to id and the search is going to be favourable because that index (of the 2 available) is the one the search would likely be based upon.

Note the above is a pretty simplistic overview it doesn't consider [The SQLite Query Planner](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) which may be of interest. The [ANALYZE statement](https://sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) may also be of interest.